# An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xunit

I have a problem with running automated tests. When I run single tests, everything is ok, but when I run a package of the test, then I get fail with info:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP 
request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49157/session//element.
```

If you need I can send all stacktrace, but from my analysis follows that the first call to my code is a method `WaitForVisible` - there was time out waiting for some webElement.
I run this package of tests on several PC and the situation is the same.

NuGet Package from the project:

- Selenium.Support - 3.141
- Selenium.WebDriver - 3.141
- DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers - 3.11.0
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - 86.0.4240.2200
  Google Chrome v 86.0.4240.111
  I also tried with other versions of Selenium, downgrade (3.14) and upgrade to prerelease (4.0.0-alpha05)

**Update:**

- I tried to run tests with different version of Selenium or ChromeDriver.
- I checked solution with `chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");`

Comment: is the space and double slash intentional in the post? or is it a typo?

Comment: I corrected the post.
There should be no space, but there is a double slash - `http://localhost:60285/session//element`